# insert variable into mysql table does not work

Tags: mysql, variables, insert

I'm trying to insert a variable into mysql table, but it does not do what i want (no error, it simply does not work)

```
$string = 'this is an example';
mysql_query("insert into tablename (columnname) values ????");
```

Anyone can help me how to insert `$string` into table tablename? I tried replacing `????` with `($string)`, `(".$string.")`, `$string`, but all of them does not insert the `$string` variable into the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may not be committing the transaction. Also, please use prepared statements instead of string interpolation.

Comment: Hi Bernie, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: `insert` statements need to be committed. Alternatively there may be an "auto-commit" setting you can use. I prefer manually committing, though. Prepared statements are covered here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: nice work. Please consider posting what you did to resolve problem as an answer. Then you can accept/upvote it; which helps others more easily identify that the problem is resolved. Happy coding.

Comment: My problem was i didn't have knowledge in mysql, i thought the syntax inside mysql_query is similar to normal php syntax. Using `'$string'` resolved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use \" (an escaped quotation mark) to include quotes inside your query, like so:

```
$string = 'this is an example';
mysql_query("insert into tablename (columnname) values (\"$string\")");
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the quote (`'`) and you should use double-quotes a your string delimiter.

```
$string = "test abc";
mysql_query("insert into t (col) values ('$string')");
```

Comment: Hi Juergen, so what can be used to replace ???? in my question? Should it be values ("'.$string.'")   ?

Comment: OK, the problem has been resolved. Thank you for all of your great helps